# EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack, DatePickerDialog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm writing an Android renderer for a Xamarin Forms custom crontrol(CustomDatePicker). I found  sample code which does the job. However there are a few lines of code that I do not understand. I'm referring to the first constructor parameter of DatePickerDialog which is a callback function. Could someone please explain the what this actually does and also if I really need all commands, for example

```
view.Date = e.Date ?
```

I'm already setting the date when "Done" button is clicked?? (this code exists).

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Common.Infrastructure.Controls.CustomDatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace Employer.Droid
{
   public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomDatePicker, EditText>
   {
     public CustomDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
     {

     }

     ///more logic

    void CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)

        {

            CustomDatePicker view = Element;

            _dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, **(o, e) =>

            {

                view.Date = e.Date;

                ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);

                Control.ClearFocus();

                _dialog = null;**

            }, year, month, day);



            _dialog.SetButton("Done", (sender, e) =>

            {

                SetDate(_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime);


            });

            _dialog.DatePicker.MinDate = (long)(DateTime.Now.Date - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack` is the method that will be executed when a new date is set DatePicker.

In your case, you will use this method to send the value from your `CustomRenderer` to your  `CustomDatePicker` in your Shared project.

I see you are also setting the value when the user clicks on the "Done" button so if you don't want to pass in an action value to the `EventHandler<DateSetEventArgs> callBack`, you can send an empty one, something like:

```
_dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) => { }, year, month, day);
```

Just make sure that on the `SetDate` method you are doing all the required steps so the Date picked is correctly set into the `Element`.

Hope this helps.-